# How to solve rzc generate exited code 1 error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

When i pulled code from team explorer in visual studio code . Rzc generate exited code 1 error occured. I am unable to build project.how to solve this error?
Target framework  .net core 3.1

Comment: We should know the details error message not just `rzc generate exited code 1 error`. Please edit the question by adding the details error message log. Like this `Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error rzc generate exited with code 1. MyWebApp.Client C:\Users\Belov Boris.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.blazor.build\0.7.0\targets\RazorCompilation.targets 184`.

Answer (score 7):

Open the Project in visual studio-> check in views folder for any files having X - red color symbol then remove that file from visual studio.

Previously you deleted the files from folder - that is the issue.

ie, Razor Engine trying to render those files, but the engine could not find the physical location of that file, that is the problem. Always delete the unwanted files using the visual studio or any project editor. That is the best practice.

Answer (score 1):

I solved rzc generate exited with code 1 microsoft.net.sdk.razor.codegeneration.targets
by undoing the changes that deleted a project from the folder in file explorer instead of visual studio.

Answer (score 1):

In your Project.csproj, you should have a piece of XML code like this:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Controllers\" />
    <Folder Include="Views\Home\" />
    <Folder Include="Views\Shared\" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

It depends on your folder structure.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using Windows 7 and getting the 'rzc generate exited with code -2147450750' while debugging a .NET Core app, try installing the standalone package: Microsoft Update Catalog - KB4457144.

I had the exact same error message (apart from the directories) on Windows 7 with a newer VC++ distribution already present.

The package contains the KB2533623 that we want. Details of KB4457144: September 11, 2018—KB4457144 (Monthly Rollup)

After installation and a reboot, `dotnet new` console goes through without an error.

Dell forum source: Microsoft Windows 7 Update KB2533623 needed to install Dell Update Package (DUP)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is a useful first answer. It seems, however, that you intended for some of these statements to be links (e.g., to the associated knowledge base reference, or the Dell forum). Can you check your answer to make sure your references are properly included?

Answer (score 0):

You are using visual studio 2019 older version then you have updated to the latest version has fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I have delete some files manually  from folder.
So i resolved that issue by deleting the unloaded files from  that deleted folder as
red cross files will be still in  our visual  studio  if we delete
them outside.

Answer (score 0):

View -> Terminal ->

`dotnet restore`

`dotnet build`

it has fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was a non exising or deleted file that was included in my project, in my specific case was app.razor.css, as soon as i removed from project, the build was successfull.